# why does mvn -v works in user folder but not in other folders?

Tags: java, maven

```
D:\>mvn -version
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
-d32          use a 32-bit data model if available
-d64          use a 64-bit data model if available
-server       to select the "server" VM
              The default VM is server.

-cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
-classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
              A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
              and ZIP archives to search for class files.
-D<name>=<value>
              set a system property
-verbose:[class|gc|jni]
              enable verbose output
-version      print product version and exit
-version:<value>
              Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
              in a future release.
              require the specified version to run
-showversion  print product version and continue
-jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
              Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
              in a future release.
              include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
-? -help      print this help message
-X            print help on non-standard options
-ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
-enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
              enable assertions with specified granularity
-da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
-disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
              disable assertions with specified granularity
-esa | -enablesystemassertions
              enable system assertions
-dsa | -disablesystemassertions
              disable system assertions
-agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
              load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
              see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
-agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
              load native agent library by full pathname
-javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
              load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
-splash:<imagepath>
              show splash screen with specified image
```

See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for more details.

D:>java
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)

From the user folder it gives appropriate version.Does not work in other folders.

Environment variables set properly.
MAVEN_HOME D:\apache-maven-3.3.9
M2 D:\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin
Path : %M2%

```
C:\Users\P1321000>mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-11T00:41:47+08:00)
Maven home: D:\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_191, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
```

Comment: How do you mean it does not work when you are on other folders? What's the error message?

Comment: C:\Users\P1321000>mvn -version It works in my user folder.It does not work in all other folders.

Comment: what is the output of 'echo %PATH%' .. is it correct? check it in both folders..

Comment: Also what is output of 'where mvn' in both directories...?

Comment: both the directories output are mentioned in the question. please check there.